# How to do this in c++ ncurses?

Tags: c++, ncurses

```
ifstream inputfile;
string line;
if (inputfile.is_open())
    {
            while (getline(inputfile,line))
            {
                    cout << line << endl;
            }
            inputfile.close(); 
    }
```

This is the behavior I want to implement in ncurses. I want to print the text content to a ncurses window instead of the console. Should I replace getline() with getstr() and printw() a char array instead of a string?

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you wanted? It's adapted from one of the basic examples [here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/helloworld.html).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <ncurses.h>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputfile("filew.txt");
    std::string line;

    initscr();

    if(inputfile.is_open())
    {
        while (inputfile >> line)
        {
            printw("%s\n", line.c_str());
        }
    } else
    {
        printw("didnt find file `file.txt`\n");
    }

    refresh();

    std::cin.ignore();
    endwin();
}
```

As we are in c++ world I'd be a bit scared that an exception might cause us to exit the program without having cleaned up using `endwin`. So I'd probably add a simple RAII wrapper to make it exception safe.

e.g.

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <ncurses.h>

class ncursewrap
{
    public:
    ncursewrap()   { initscr();    }
    ~ncursewrap()  { endwin();     }
    void refresh() { ::refresh();  }
};

int main()
{
    std::ifstream inputfile("file.txt");
    std::string line;

    ncursewrap nc;

    if(inputfile.is_open())
    {
        while (inputfile >> line)
        {
            printw("%s\n", line.c_str());
        }
    } else
    {
        printw("didnt find file `file.txt`\n");
    }

    nc.refresh();

    std::cin.ignore();
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This was really helpful. Should a wrapper always be used with ncurses?

Comment: I'd be surprised if there are aren't a few out there already which should simplify things. Its probably a good idea, as its very difficult to keep track of which exceptions are thrown where and its better to have the protection of the wrapper which cleans up in a destructor.

Comment: feel free to upvote & accept if its what you wanted.